# Dimension of configuration space of triangulated convex polyhedron

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra, configuration-spaces

The configuration space of all tetrahedra is $5$-dimensional, perhaps a non-obvious fact.
There are $12$ face angles, but the sum of each of the four faces angles is $\pi$,
reducing $12$ to $8$ degrees of freedom. There are, however, additional trigonometric
relations that must be satisfied by the angles, as cited in the
[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#A_law_of_sines_for_tetrahedra_and_the_space_of_all_shapes_of_tetrahedra).
This reduces the dimension of the configuration space to $5$ dimensions.

---

[image]

<sup>Wikipedia image: product of sines of marked angles are equal.</sup>

---

My question is:

> Is there a generalization to other triangulated convex polyhedra?

For example, consider the space of all convex polyhedra that are combinatorially
equivalent to a regular octahedron. Here we have $24$ face angles ($4$ per vertex), but then
$8$ triangle angles summing to $\pi$ reduces the $24$ to $16$ degrees of freedom.
Presumably there are additional trigonometric relations that further
reduce the dimension of the configuration space. My *guess* is to $10$ dimensions.

Perhaps it is better to think in terms of vertex coordinates rather than in
terms of face angles?

Comment: Related question with answer on M.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4108507/415941. The post gives an intuition for why the dimension is close to the number of edges. And the comments mention that this holds for non-simplicial polyhedra as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simplicial polyhedra, one can simply add up the degrees of freedom from placing the vertices in space and substract 7 degrees of freedom for rotation, translation, and scaling to obtain $3v-7$ as in Alexandre Eremenko's answer.

Comment: Very clear and concise---Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A convex polyhedron can be considered as a flat metric with conic singularities
on the sphere. This metric is completely determined (up to a constant factor)
by conformal structure of the sphere with $v$ marked points ($v$ is the number of vertices) and $v$ angles around these points (sums of angles of faces meeting at a vertex). Three points can be fixed and the rest
depend of $2$ real parameters each. The angles satisfy one relation (coming from Gauss-Bonnet). So the total number of parameters is
$$2(v-3)+v-1=3v-7.$$
For the tetrahedron, $v=4$ and we obtain $5$.

(Since your argument involves only angles, I suppose you counted tetrahedra up to scaling, as I did).

The fact that every flat metric with conic singularities and angles
$<2\pi$ at each singularity corresponds to a convex polytope embedded in $R^3$ is non-trivial, but I suppose it is true.

Remark: Your condition that it is "triangulated", if I understand it
correctly, is irrelevant: the surface of any convex polytope can be triangulated without adding new vertices.

Remark 2: this answer is less elementary but contains some extra information in comparison with Yoav Kallus's answer: it gives a global parametrization of the set of convex polytopes, not only the dimension count. It also works for hyperbolic or spherical polytopes (assuming that the angles are less than $2\pi$.

Comment: You can also get the same answer from the vertex coordinates: 3v before rotation (3), translation (3) and scaling (1).

Comment: That is a much simpler argument; why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Done. Regarding your first remark, I think the point is that a triangular bipyramid will have one more degree of freedom than a quadrilateral pyramid because of the extra constraint that the four points on the quadrilateral faces be coplanar.

Comment: Very insightful---Thanks. I believe it is Alexandrov's "Gluing theorem" which guarantees that "every flat metric with conic singularities and angles $<2\pi$ at each singularity corresponds to a convex polytope embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$."

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: You are right; at the time of writing I just forgot who proved this (Alexandrov or Pogorelov).